# What is the remainder when $7^{113}$ is divided by $50$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What is the remainder when $7^{113}$ is divided by $50$? is there any method to approach such question

Comment: Hint: $7^2 = 49 = 50 - 1$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compute $a^b\,\bmod c$ by hand?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81228/how-do-i-compute-ab-bmod-c-by-hand)

Comment: No, there is no method to approach such a question. That's why no teacher has ever asked a class to solve such a question.

Answer (score 3):

We know that $7^2=49 \equiv -1 \pmod{50}$, so we can write, that:

$$7^{113}=7 \times (7^2)^{56} \equiv 7 \times (-1)^{56} \equiv 7 \pmod{50}$$

Comment: `\pmod{50}` is the correct operator for what you want to achieve;  the p in pmod means adding extra parentheses the correct way (this is how I remember it).

Comment: @HennoBrandsma thank you very much, I'll remember it now!